# Как сократить объем выводимого текста?

Tags: c#, html, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Проблема такая: есть модель "News" с параметрами "NewsId", "Title" и "Content". В представлении я вывожу эти новости:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (News n in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2>@n.Title</h2>
            <p>@n.Content</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">Далее &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

В HomeController написал так:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Электронная библиотека";
    var news = db.News.OrderBy(News => News.NewsId).Skip(Math.Max(0, db.News.Count() - 3));
    return View(news);
}
```

А в представлении задействовал это:

```
@using libapp.Models;
@model IEnumerable<News>
```

Всё работает на ура, я вывожу последние три новости, однако содержание (*Content*) у каждой новости разное, и поэтому получается вот это:
[image: Новости]

Как сократить выводимый в параметре Content текст? что бы блоки с текстом были ну хотя бы примерно одинаковых размеров.

Comment: Делайте на стороне отображения. С помощью разметки и css

Comment: @srvr4vr каким образом?

Comment: У вас заголовок не соответствует телу вопроса. Сократить объём текста и сделать блоки одинаковых размеров - разные вещи. Уточните, что именно нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое простое, что приходит в голову - выводить не весь контент, а только подстроку определенного размера.

Метод, если не ошибаюсь - substring

UPD:

Реализовать можно примерно так: в контроллере, перед передачей данных в view, пройтись по каждой записи и поле с контентом обрезать по необходимому кол-ву символов.

Чтобы не сильно больно выглядело, можно что-то придумать с концом текста. Добавлять "..." или что-то подобное.

Немного измененный пример с обрезанием текста из документации:

```
string [] info = { "Name: Felica Walker", "Title: Mz.", 
                   "Age: 47", "Location: Paris", "Gender: F"};

int found = 0;

// Полная информация
Console.WriteLine("The initial values in the array are:");
foreach (string s in info)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

Console.WriteLine();

// Обрезаем строки для вывода значений    
foreach (string s in info) 
{
    found = s.IndexOf(": ");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s.Substring(found + 2));
}

Console.WriteLine();

// Обрезаем строки для вывода ключей      
foreach (string s in info) 
{
    found = s.IndexOf(": ");
    Console.WriteLine("   {0}", s.Substring(0, found));
}
```

Comment: Шрифт не моноширинный, поэтому длина в пикселях текстов с одинаковым количеством символов будет разной. Во-вторых, из-за переносов слов на другую строку в разных текстах будет вставляться разное количество пробелов. В итоге вариант будет малорабочим. Кто плюсует - я хз...

Comment: @raspberry367 можете попобробнее описать каким образом?

Comment: @Dmitry обновил

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Плюсуют наверно потому, что был дан ответ на вопрос, нет? Ну т.е вопрос был именно как сократить текст, а не как сделать так, чтобы еще отображалось посимпотишнее) Я лишь предложил свой вариант. Критикуешь чужое, предлагай свое (с) :)

Comment: Суть вопроса всё-таки в том, чтобы сделать блоки одинаковых размеров. Substring тут никак не поможет. Вопрос именно по разметке, именно про "симпотишность".